# cannot send Arabic text in post request

Tags: json, spring-boot, http, http-headers, resttemplate

I still a beginner with spring boot, I'm facing problem with `resTemplet` here I'm fetching the data from DB by using JPA and post them through HTTP post request, everything is okay when `messageBody` is english but for arabic language the message looks like unreadable  , the problem only with Arabic message, I have read a lot about this thing and I followed some recommendations like :

1- setup `application.properties` like :

```
spring.http.encoding.charset=UTF-8
spring.http.encoding.enabled=true
spring.http.encoding.force=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.connection.characterEncoding=utf-8
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.connection.CharSet=utf-8
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.connection.useUnicode=true
server.tomcat.uri-encoding=UTF-8
```

2- I have tried `StringHttpMessageConverter` but does not add any value

```
restMessengerTemplate = new RestTemplate();
restMessengerHeader = new HttpHeaders();
restMessengerHeader.setAccept(Arrays.asList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
restMessengerHeader.add("Authorization",
                "Basic " + Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(("user:password").getBytes()));
```

but the problem still exists also i have tried `headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8);` but it returns  The field MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8 is deprecated

code :

```
public class Messenger {

    private static Messenger instance = new Messenger();
    private static final RestTemplate restMessengerTemplate;
    private static final HttpHeaders restMessengerHeader;
    private HttpEntity<VasGateway> smsEntity;
    private ResponseEntity<String> messengerResponseEntity;

    static {
        restMessengerTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        restMessengerTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(0, new StringHttpMessageConverter(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        restMessengerHeader = new HttpHeaders();
        restMessengerHeader.setAccept(Arrays.asList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
        restMessengerHeader.add("Authorization",
                "Basic " + Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(("user:password").getBytes()));
                }
    private Messenger() {

    }

    public static Messenger getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }

    public String call(String messageId, String msisdn, String messageBody, String language) throws Exception {
        smsEntity = new HttpEntity<VasGateway>(
        new VasGateway(new Sendsms(new ArrayList<Message>(
        Collections.singletonList(new Message(messageId, "Test", msisdn,
        messageBody, language.equalsIgnoreCase("EN") ? "0" : "2"))))),restMessengerHeader);
        messengerResponseEntity = restMessengerTemplate.exchange("http link",
        HttpMethod.POST, smsEntity, String.class);
        return "0";
    }

}
```

my concern in arabic text at `messageBody`, im using oracle 11g with encoding type:`AR8ISO8859P6` :

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonPropertyOrder({ "messages" })
public class Sendsms {

    @JsonProperty("messages")
    private List<Message> messages = null;

    public Sendsms() {
    }

    public Sendsms(List<Message> messages) {
        this.messages = messages;
    }
```

message class :

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonPropertyOrder({ "msgid", "from", "to", "text", "coding" })
public class Message {

    @JsonProperty("msgid")
    private String msgid;
    @JsonProperty("from")
    private String from;
    @JsonProperty("to")
    private String to;
    @JsonProperty("text")
    private String text;
    @JsonProperty("coding")
    private String coding;

    public Message() {
    }

    public Message(String msgid, String from, String to, String text, String coding) {
        this.msgid = msgid;
        this.from = from;
        this.to = to;
        this.text = text;
        this.coding = coding;
    }
```

vasGetwayclass :

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonPropertyOrder({ "sendsms" })
public class VasGateway {

    @JsonProperty("sendsms")
    private Sendsms sendsms;

    public VasGateway() {
    }

    public VasGateway(Sendsms sendsms) {
        this.sendsms = sendsms;
    }
```

Comment: When you say you have problems, what specific problems are you having? What is the database engine and what encoding is it using? What is the exact format of your POST request (i.e. what bytes are you actually sending?) What exactly is the Message type (is it part of one of these libraries, or is it a custom class)? How does Sendsms operate on the string? There's very little information here to work with. Simplify this to the smallest example you can. But a test app that just sends one hard-coded message and get ride of all the rest of the code.

Comment: thank you for your replay dear, this operation works fine with English language, the problem when i set`messageBody` to Arabic it returns unreadable data, im trying to use utf8 to handle, i will update my question with more info , thank you for help

Comment: @RobNapier i have updated my question ,  this work  with no error the issue only in `messageBody` return rabish text for arabic text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> my concern in arabic text at messageBody, im using oracle 11g with encoding type:AR8ISO8859P6 :

You're encoding in the database in ISO 8859-6 (i.e. Latin/Arabic), but your code expects UTF-8. At some point you're going to need to convert between the two. Ideally you should convert the database to work in UTF-8 directly. But if you can't do that, you're going to have to do translation when moving between the database and UTF-8 JSON.

Comment: i have tried url encoding `URLEncoder.encode(stringToBeEncoded, "UTF-8")` and`UTF-16` but still the text is not clear , do you have any idea how can i make translation ?

Comment: after check for example i have this text : `مرحبا` to be valid in post method and readable it should be encoded like this : `06450631062d06280627` , but i cannot figure out what encoding happened or what should I do, i have tried `utf-8` and `utf16` but they are different from the desired encoding

Comment: That's UTF-16BE (big-endian). A convenient way to work this out is to take the first character (م), and search for it at fileformat.info: https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0645/index.htm Looking in the Encodings table will show you that 0x0645 is its UTF-16 encoding. If it is a more unusual encoding, you can click "more" and check this page: https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0645/charset_support.htm